Foreign key constraint violated: Order_userId_fkey (index) at async $$ACTION_0 (./src/app/configure/preview/actions.ts:50:17) digest: "2130770760"
I am working on a ecommerce website build on nextjs.
Below is my schema.primsa
generator client {
provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
provider = "postgresql"
url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

enum OrderStatus {
fulfilled
shipped
awaiting_shipment
}

enum PhoneModel {
iphonex
iphone11
iphone12
iphone13
iphone14
iphone15
}

enum CaseMaterial {
silicone
polycarbonate
}

enum CaseFinish {
smooth
textured
}

enum CaseColor {
black
blue
rose
}

model Configuration {
id              String        @id @default(cuid())
width           Int
height          Int
imageUrl        String
color           CaseColor?
model           PhoneModel?
material        CaseMaterial?
finish          CaseFinish?
croppedImageUrl String?
Order           Order\[\]
}

model User {
id    String  @id @default(cuid())
email String
Order Order\[\]

createdAt DateTime @default(now())
updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Order {
id              String        @id @default(cuid())
configurationId String
configuration   Configuration @relation(fields: \[configurationId\], references: \[id\])
user            User          @relation(fields: \[userId\], references: \[id\])
userId          String
amount          Float
isPaid          Boolean       @default(false)
status          OrderStatus   @default(awaiting_shipment)

shippingAddress   ShippingAddress? @relation(fields: \[shippingAddressId\], references: \[id\])
shippingAddressId String?
billingAddress    BillingAddress?  @relation(fields: \[billingAddressId\], references: \[id\])
billingAddressId  String?

createdAt DateTime @default(now())
updated   DateTime @updatedAt
}

model ShippingAddress {
id          String  @id @default(cuid())
name        String
street      String
city        String
postalCode  String
country     String
state       String?
phoneNumber String?
orders      Order\[\]
}

model BillingAddress {
id          String  @id @default(cuid())
name        String
street      String
city        String
postalCode  String
country     String
state       String?
phoneNumber String?
orders      Order\[\]
}
\

error shown in my terminal is:
⨯ PrismaClientKnownRequestError:  Invalid `prisma.order.create()\` invocation:

Foreign key constraint violated: `Order_userId_fkey (index)`
at async $$ACTION_0 (./src/app/configure/preview/actions.ts:50:17)
digest: "2130770760"
POST /configure/preview?id=cm2emlsrz0000jh7mycsv0bh4 500 in 627ms\

my actions.js file is:
"use server";

import { BASE_PRICE, PRODUCT_PRICES } from "@/config/products";
import { db } from "@/db";
import { stripe } from "@/lib/stripe";
import { getKindeServerSession } from "@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server";
import { Order } from "@prisma/client";

export const createCheckoutSession = async ({
configId,
}: {
configId: string;
}) =\> {
const configuration = await db.configuration.findUnique({
where: { id: configId },
});

if (!configuration) {
throw new Error("Configuration not found");
}

const { getUser } = getKindeServerSession();
const user = await getUser();
if (!user) {
throw new Error("You need to be logged in");
}

const { finish, material } = configuration;

let price = BASE_PRICE;
if (finish === "textured") price += PRODUCT_PRICES.finish.textured;
if (material === "polycarbonate")
price += PRODUCT_PRICES.material.polycarbonate;

let order: Order | undefined = undefined;

const existingOrder = await db.order.findFirst({
where: {
userId: user.id,
configurationId: configuration.id,
},
});

console.log(user.id, configuration.id);

if (existingOrder) {
order = existingOrder;
} else {
order = await db.order.create({
data: {
amount: price / 100,
userId: user.id,
configurationId: configuration.id,
},
});
}

const product = await stripe.products.create({
name: "Custom Iphone cover",
images: \[configuration.imageUrl\],
default_price_data: {
currency: "USD",
unit_amount: price,
},
});

const stripeSession = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
success_url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/thank-you?orderId=${order.id}`,
cancel_url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/configure/preview?id=${configuration.id}`,
payment_method_types: \["card", "paypal"\],
mode: "payment",
shipping_address_collection: {
allowed_countries: \["IN", "US", "DE"\],
},
metadata: {
userId: user.id,
orderId: order.id,
},
line_items: \[
{
price: product.default_price as string,
quantity: 1,
},
\],
});
return { url: stripeSession.url };
};

I am unable to push the data in the database. By using
npx prisma studio

I check the table is there but data is not creating.
I need to fix it.
Can anyone please help me in this
I have tried to fix it by configure the db and prisma correctly. The error may be in
if (existingOrder) {
    order = existingOrder;
  } else {
    order = await db.order.create({
      data: {
        amount: price / 100,
        userId: user.id,
        configurationId: configuration.id,
      },
    });
  }


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
